# Why the float cannot give exactly 0 value?

Tags: visual-c++

I have a question. Below is my code. I am wonder why, my output for "err3" cannot give a value of 0 ? is it because of the datatype is float?

The output are as below:

the value of err1 is -7.03125e-06
the value of err2 is 7.03125e-06
the value of err3 is -4.54747e-13

the operation between err1 and err2 is + and thus, the value for err3 should be 0.

can anyone help me to explain and solve this problem? I have google but still did not get the result.

Thanks in advance :)

```
void calnormal()
{
long numcal;
float indexNC0,indexNC1;
float error;

float aa0 = 0, ab0 = 0, ac0 = 0, ad0 = 0;
float          bb0 = 0, bc0 = 0, bd0 = 0;
float                   cc0 = 0, cd0 = 0;
float                            dd0 = 0;

float aa, ab, ac, ad;
float     bb, bc, bd;
float         cc, cd;
float             dd;

for(int i=0;i<noofvert;i++)
{
    numcal = vlist[i].returnsizef();
    for(int j=0;j<numcal;j=j+2)
    {
        indexNC0 = vlist[i].returnindexf(j);
        u.ax = vlist[i].returnx() - vlist[indexNC0].returnx();
        u.ay = vlist[i].returny() - vlist[indexNC0].returny();
        u.az = vlist[i].returnz() - vlist[indexNC0].returnz();
        if(j == 0){v0 = u;}

        indexNC1 = vlist[i].returnindexf(j+1);
        v.ax = vlist[i].returnx() - vlist[indexNC1].returnx();
        v.ay = vlist[i].returny() - vlist[indexNC1].returny();
        v.az = vlist[i].returnz() - vlist[indexNC1].returnz();

        normal.ax = u.ay * v.az - u.az * v.ay;
        normal.ay = u.az * v.ax - u.ax * v.az;
        normal.az = u.ax * v.ay - u.ay * v.ax;

        normal.D = - vlist[i].returnx() * normal.ax -    vlist[i].returny() * normal.ay - vlist[i].returnz() * normal.az;

        aa = normal.ax * normal.ax;
        ab = normal.ax * normal.ay;
        ac = normal.ax * normal.az;
        ad = normal.ax * normal.D;

        bb = normal.ay * normal.ay;
        bc = normal.ay * normal.az;
        bd = normal.ay * normal.D;

        cc = normal.az * normal.az;
        cd = normal.az * normal.D;

        dd = normal.D * normal.D;

        aa0 = aa0 + aa;
        ab0 = ab0 + ab;    bb0 = bb0 + bb;
        ac0 = ac0 + ac;    bc0 = bc0 + bc;    cc0 = cc0 + cc;
        ad0 = ad0 + ad;    bd0 = bd0 + bd;    cd0 = cd0 + cd;    dd0 = dd0 + dd;


    }

    double err1,err2,err3;

    **err1 = cd0 * vlist[i].returnz();
    err2 = dd0 ;

    err3 = err2 + err1;
    cout  <<  err1 << " " << err2 << " " << err3 << endl;**


    cout << endl;
}
cout << endl;
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

err3 is very close to zero, 13 zeros. err1 and err2 have 6 zeros.

A float can store about 7 decimal digits of precision.

If you had printed out more decimals of err1 and err2 you probably see they are not exactly the same. Because err1 and err2 is float they store 7 digits of precision. They probably differ a little bit in the last digit (0.5zeros+7digits) and substracting them give a result with 0.000..00x (13 zeros).

A double have roughly a maximum of 16 decimal digits of precision. When you do computations, you lose a little precision for every operation because every result is truncated to about 16 decimal digits. If you in the end end up with 13 digits of precision it is fully normal.

Comment: Actually the datatype should be float. From my understanding the difference between float and double is the range, am I correct? and how am I going to fix this problem? I have stuck for a week to this problem.